# C++ how to infer the Callable's type (arguments list & return value) in a template

Tags: c++, templates, functional-programming, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Basically what I want to do, is to make a function template, that takes any Callable (function type / lambda / Functor) and returns a lambda-taking-the-similar-args-list and returning the type of original's return type

```
#include <iostream>

int func(int a,float b) {
    return a+b;
}

struct callable {
    int operator() (int a, float b) {
        return a+b;
    }
};

template <typename RV, typename... Args>
auto getLambdaFromCallable(RV(&func)(Args...)) {
    auto l = [&](Args... args) -> RV {
        return func(args...);
    };

    return l;
}

int main() {
    auto f = getLambdaFromCallable(func);
    std::cout << f(1,2.f);
    std::cout << " " << typeid(f).name();

    auto f2 = getLambdaFromCallable(callable{}); // doesn't work
    callable{}(1,2); // works

    auto lambdaTest = [](int a, float b) -> int {
        return a+b;
    };
    auto f3 = getLambdaFromCallable(lambdaTest);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change `getLambdaFromCallable` to:

```
template <typename F>
auto getLambdaFromFunction(const F& func) {
  auto l = [&](auto&&... args) 
    -> decltype(func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)) {
    return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
  };

  return l;
}
```

The reasoning behind this is that since you cannot get an exhaustive list of argument you can call a function object with (there might be multiple overloads in the first place), you might as well use a generic lambda which accepts everything and forward it to the callable.

---

To elaborate more about how this works:

- The `auto&&...` part gets converted to a template argument list on the lambda's call operator.
- `F` is deduced to whatever you called the `getLambdaFromFunction` with (without the `const` and reference but that can be changed if needed).
- `decltype(args)` is just there to use `std::forward` which in turn is there to correctly forward both lvalue and rvalue references, see [std::forward](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) for more details.

The generated lambda object will look like this:

```
template <typename F>
class generatedLambda
{
public:
  template <typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&... args) -> decltype(func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))
  {
    return func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
  }

private:
  F     func;
};
```

Comment: `-> decltype(auto)` for the return type of the lambda (to handle reference).

Comment: Or even `-> decltype(func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))`, so it is SFINAE friendly.

Comment: @Jarod42 can you please elaborate how this works? So the lambda itself is a template, right? auto&&... is a variadic templated argument list, right? so it deduces the func's type F as a "reference to callable?" what does the decltype(args) do?

Comment: @barney Tried to answer your questions in the second part of the answer

Comment: @Drax oh, thank you, this is amazing solution to the problem

Comment: You can also add an exception specification, if you feel like repeating `func(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...)` a third time. Gotta love C++ sometimes...

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17, [std::invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) is the right tool:

```
#include <functional>

template <typename OBJ>
auto getLambdaFromCallable(OBJ&& obj)
{
  return [&](const auto&... args) { 
                return std::invoke(std::forward<OBJ>(obj), args...); 
         };
}
```

You can compile it with `g++ -std=c++17` or `clang++-5.0 -std=c++1z` and this is working out of the box.

Comment: @barney thanks. I assumed that the inputs are not modified which also simplify things concerning argument forwarding, here I have a simple const ref instead. I also like Drax solution which is explained in all details.